# Abnormal output of windows-thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

i'm new to c++ and experimenting a bit around. I started to create a thread using  and the CreateThread-Method. I also pass in a pointer to a struct-method, which references a test-value. So far so good. Now i changed the value BEFORE starting the thread to 0. When i start the program, evrything seems to be working like i expected. But when i change the value also AFTER the CreateThread-Method (to 1), the thread outputs always 1. I expected an output of 0, because i thought that changes to a variable does not affect the thread. Or at least an output of 0 first of all and then 1.

Now i tested something:
If i let the main-thread wait for example 5000ms, then the output of the thread is again always 0. But without it is 1 again.

I hope you can help me with the understanding of that problem.

Here is some code:

```
struct TESTSTRUCT{
  int test;
};

DWORD WINAPI testFunc(void* lpParam){

  TESTSTRUCT& params=*((TESTSTRUCT*)lpParam);

  int a=params.test;

  while(true){
      cout << a;
      Sleep(5000);
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  TESTSTRUCT teststr;
  teststr.test=0;
  HANDLE myhandle;
  myhandle = CreateThread(0, 0, testFunc, &teststr, 0, 0);

  Sleep(5000); // If left out, thread outputs always 1!

  teststr.test=1;

  cout << "main" << teststr.test;

  CloseHandle(myhandle);

  MSG msg;
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: The OS gets to decide when `teststr.test` is assigned.  This is a classic race condition that generally is handled via locking.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I mean it is in the main-function and someone would expect assigning first value 0 and than 1. Or does the compiler compile in the other way round? (from bottom to top for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

```
 myhandle = CreateThread(0, 0, testFunc, &teststr, 0, 0);
```

You are passing your `teststr` by reference to your `testFunc`. Therefore your `main` method and your `testFunc` are operating on the same data. Changing one will affect the other.

To be clear, the way it works is that you are getting the address of `teststr`, casting it to `void*`, and then within `testFunc` you are casting it back to `TESTSTRUCT&`. This is the same thing as if you just passed `teststr` to `testFunc` by reference.

I suppose I should mention that without locking you have a race condition on the output of the thread, no matter what the sleep period is. Make `main` sleep long enough and in general you'll see your thread print the 'old' value, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Okay this makes sense now! But how can i avoid it, since the CreateThread-method only allows to pass pointers. I just want to achieve, that the threads keep the values they got passed. How should i do this?

Comment: It is safe to cast an suitably-sized integer to a void pointer and back.  But in the general case, you could simply make a copy of the data and pass the thread a pointer to the copy.  (In practice, most of the time the main thread doesn't need to access the data that you've passed to the new thread, so you don't need to do anything.)

Comment: Well i also tried it with a global int-variable. I set up a mutex for the cout, but it seems that the created thread does not copy the global variable. So if i first set the var to 0, create the Thread and then set the var again to 1, the created thread ouputs still 1. I don't get that really. With a struct everything works as i expected, but not with a simple variable. Why is that so?

Comment: What you need to do is create a second int variable that is equal to the first. Pass the second one to your thread, and now the thread essentially receives a copy. Or, you could create the copy inside the thread itself from the received argument